# Access to a var in another file

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is it possible to access to a var or a function that is in another file?. In this case, when the user click to #linkajax can he get what is in var test? how can I do it? I tried this and it does not work

JQUERY AJAX:

```
$("#linkajax").click(function(){
    $("#target").load("extern.html");
    $('#target').text(test);
});
```

INDEX.HTML:

```
<div id="linkajax">just clic!</div>
<br>
<div id="target"></div>
```

EXTERN.HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var test = "test text"; 
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Is `EXTERN.HTML` literally just a script tag? Or is there actual HTML markup on that page as well? Because if it's nothing but a script with a variable in it, you should really be using JSON and `ajax()` not HTML and `load()`. The `load()` method will load HTML and place it into `#target` automatically. There is no need to use the callback function and jQuery to populate the contents of the element.

Comment: @Brian: is html and there is more things in it. I just simplify the case to explain here

Comment: So then why are you loading the HTML into the div, then replacing the div with the contents of a script tag in the HTML you just loaded into the div? It would seem to make more sense to just use JSON to load the JS variables you need to populate the div instead of loading an entire page of HTML code into it, then parsing a global variable out of that HTML and replacing the HTML with the contents of that variable.

Comment: @Brian I do not know Jason, I do not know how to do what you say.

Comment: @Nrc check my answer. I updated it to show what I mean.

Comment: Why the negative points. This cannot be found in the web and here nobody knows the answer. It must not be such an easy question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when the file is loaded it is possible. Try with `jQuery.ajax()` (if `external.html` is in the same domain):

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url: "external.html",
   dataType: "html",
   success: function (data) {
        html = jQuery.parseHTML(data, document, true);
        jQuery("#target").append(html);
        jQuery("#target").text(test);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have checked that the file is loaded. How can I get the var?

Comment: As I told to Brian I copy paste your code of the external.json in a new file with just that code and the code editor gives me an error

Comment: @Nrc Your editor supports JSON? In any case, if you run it in a browser, it works.

Comment: I  use Dreamweaver I think it supports json?. But yes it works in a browser.

Comment: I completed your first solution with jQuery("#target").text(data.test); and it does not work. Does it mean that the extern file must be json, is there any way to make it work wihth a normal html file?

Comment: Sorry, I really appreciate your effort but it does not wor

Comment: @Nrc Definitely this must be fault of Dreamweaver. Any of these solutions work in most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ultimately load the result of a JS variable into the element, then JSON is a better approach than loading HTML, parsing a script inside it to populate a global variable, and then reading that variable to populate the div thus replacing the HTML you just loaded. To do this, use `ajax()` instead of `load()` like so:

```
$("#linkajax").click(function(){
    $("#target").ajax("EXTERN.JSON",{
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#target').text( data.test );
        }
    });
});
```

The contents of `EXTERN.JSON` would be:

```
{"test":"test text"}
```

Comment: I would note that there are much better implementations of this functionality such as using `$.ajax` instead and returning JSON which contains both the markup to insert into `#target` and the data to pass into your `text` call. This would be much more foolproof than relying on a globally namespaced variable to carry information that is ultimately local in nature.

Comment: I already tried your first solution before asking and it does not work, when I click there is nothing. The second option with ajax, can you give a example applied to this case? or where can I find information? I know a bit ajax but not json

Comment: I copy paste your code in a new file called extern.json and the code editor gives me an error. It is the first time I use json. Do I need anything else?

Comment: Nope, that should be all you need in there. I would also point you toward the [JSON Tutorial @W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/json/) to help get you up to speed on it.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to access a variable defined somewhere in another javascript file that is loaded asynchronously. You can refer the [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762243/having-difficulty-working-with-global-variables-and-getscript) for the reference.

Hope it helps ..